# In spring kafka if the listener container is paused then can it emit ListenerContainerIdleEvent (idle event)?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

If the listener container has been paused will it still emit ListenerContainerIdleEvent after the threshold set in setIdleEventInterval has exceeded ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the paused state of the container is not considered when deciding to emit idle events.

However, the event contains a property...

```java
/**
 * Return true if the consumer was paused at the time the idle event was published.
 * @return paused.
 * @since 2.1.5
 */
public boolean isPaused() {
    return this.paused;
}
```